# What are the uses cases of omitempty in a Go struct?

Tags: oop, go, struct

I'm curious what the use cases are for omit empty with the following:

```
type Example struct {
    ID           string  `json:",omitempty"`
    Name         string  `json:"name,omitempty"`
    exchangeRate float64 `json:"string"`
}
```

I've read that `omitempty` prevents an empty value from showing up when the struct is printed, but I'm not positive about that. 
Also, why would you include the name of the struct value i.e. `Name`, and `omitempty`?

Comment: See the [encoding/json package documentation](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal) for information about the field tags in the example struct.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Cerise Limon for suggesting checking out the godocs at godoc.org.

According to the section on marshalling JSON:

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field
>   becomes a member of the object, using the field name as the object
>   key, unless the field is omitted.
>
> The field of each string can be customized by the format string stored
>   under the json key in the struct field's tag.  The format string gives
>   the name of the field, possibly followed by a comma separated list of
>   options.
>
> The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from
>   the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a
>   nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map,
>   or string.

```
// Field appears in JSON as key "myName".
Field int `json:"myName"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "myName" and
// the field is omitted from the object if its value is empty,
// as defined above.
Field int `json:"myName,omitempty"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "Field" (the default), but
// the field is skipped if empty.
// Note the leading comma.
Field int `json:",omitempty"`

// Field is ignored by this package.
Field int `json:"-"`

// Field appears in JSON as key "-".
Field int `json:"-,"`
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation, however, you also forgot to mention that if omitempty is used, rest all validations are skipped.